# реализация ЕСИА на сайте

Tags: c#, авторизация, oauth, аутентификация

Добрый день! Встал вопрос прикрутить авторизацию на сайте через есиа (Госуслуги). 
Наверняка кто-то уже проделывал это! Помогите пожалуйста, я от этого очень далека, а сделать надо...

В общем, имеется сайт на ASP.NET (c#, Windows Forms).

Выбранный тип аутентификации - OAuth 2.0 и OpenID Connect 1.0.

Уже, как указано, на сайте минкомсвязи сформировали заявку на подключение к тестовой среде ЕСИА. Заявку одобрили, прислали документ с инструкцией и 3 файла. В инструкии как таковых шагов нет, только логины и пароли для входа на госуслуги тестовые и описание того, что должно прийти в ответ.

Файлы типа .rar - по инструкции это якобы контейнеры с ключами для ЭЦП.
например, архив EsiaTest.006.rar содержит такие файлы:

- header.key
- masks.key
- masks2.key
- name.key
- primary.key
- primary2.key

Все параметры для авторизации в принципе понятны, кроме как раз подписи.
Вот как раз с формированием ЭЦП у меня проблемы.

В документе сказано формировать ее так:

> Подпись запроса в формате PKCS#7 detached signature в кодировке UTF-8 от значений четырех параметров HTTP–запроса: scope, timestamp, clientId, state (они у меня есть). Подпись должна быть закодирована в формате base64 url safe. Используемый для проверки подписи сертификат должен быть предварительно зарегистрирован в ЕСИА и привязан к учетной записи системы-клиента в ЕСИА. ЕСИА поддерживает сертификаты в формате X.509. ЕСИА поддерживает алгоритмы формирования электронной подписи RSA с длиной ключа 2048 и алгоритмом криптографического хэширования SHA-256, а также алгоритм электронной подписи ГОСТ Р 34.10-2001 и алгоритм криптографического хэширования ГОСТ Р 34.11-94.

Помогите сформировать эту подпись! Как все это реализовать на c# ?
Заранее благодарю

Comment: опенссл или криптопро тебе нужны

Comment: @eri КриптоПро есть. Я так понимаю мне надо как то на основе ключей (файлов .key, который мне прислали) сформировать сертификат и с помощью него подписать запрос? Так это работает?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа). Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Шаги по интеграции вы вряд ли где-то найдете. Есть только методические рекомендации и регламент работы с ЕСИА, но адекватного описания процедуры "как это сделать на C#" там нет :)

То, что вам прислали вместе с ответом на заявку — это просто примеры разных тестовых аккаунтов для отладки работы, т.е. это НИКАК НЕ СВЯЗАНО с подписью ваших запросов к ЕСИА.

Вот команды которыми мы генерирует правильный сертификат:

```
openssl req -nodes -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout secret.key -out request.csr -subj /C=RU/ST=Rostov-na-Donu/L=city/O=COMPANY\/emailAddress=EMAIL@site.ru/

openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 3650 -in request.csr -signkey secret.key -out cert.crt -extfile /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf -extensions v3_ca

openssl x509 -in cert.crt -text
```

Соответственно в нужные места нужно подставить правильные данные о компании почту и т.п.
это команда работает под линуксом
при этом в файле /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf надо добавить(изменить) следующую секцию:

```
[ v3_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical CA
# PKIX recommendation.
keyUsage = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = emailProtection, clientAuth
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
```

в результате вы получите работающий сертификат cert.crt и ключ secret.key

Но это будет только начало. Там еще вагон и маленькая тележка нюансов по части обмена данными с ЕСИА.

Вот тут есть готовое решение, в т.ч. и на C#: [esia.pro](http://esia.pro)

Оно платное, но помимо готовой реализации там еще проконсультируют по процессу интеграции и оргвопросам.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я уже в принципе на пути подписания строки сертификатом. Правда подпись не проходит и валится. Еще в инструкции написано: электронная подпись сотрудника Организации должна быть сформирована с помощью закрытого
ключа, прилагаемого к инструкции. Собственно это и есть файлы закрытого ключа в архиве. Сертификаты гостовские. Сейчас бьюсь с   CryptoPro.Sharpei. Может  у вас с этой библиотекой есть опыт работы? тоже нужна помощь

Answer (score 2):

У нас подпись заработала как-то так:

```
public static byte[] Sign(X509Certificate2 certificate, byte[] data)
{
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
    if (certificate == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");

    // setup the data to sign
    ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, true);
    CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(certificate);
    var sha256 = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1", "sha256");
    signer.DigestAlgorithm = sha256;

    // create the signature
    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
    var signature = signedCms.Encode();

    return signature;
}
```

С base64 там всё не очевидно: Convert.ToBase64String не подходит, не достаточно точно реализует стандарт.
Использовал вот такой метод:

```
public static string Base64UrlEncode(byte[] arg)
{
    string s = Convert.ToBase64String(arg); // Regular base64 encoder
    s = s.Split('=')[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
    s = s.Replace('+', '-'); // 62nd char of encoding
    s = s.Replace('/', '_'); // 63rd char of encoding
    return s;
}
```

Проверка их подписи - это очередной ребус. Можно предположить, что это процесс обратный процессу подписания, т.е. как-то так:

```
public static bool ValidateCmsSignature(byte[] data, byte[] signature, X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
    if (signature == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("signature");
    if (certificate == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");

    // setup the data to sign
    ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, true);

    try
    {
        signedCms.Decode(signature);
        signedCms.CheckSignature(new X509Certificate2Collection(certificate), true);
        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var msg = ex.Message;
    }

    return result;
}
```

И этот метод работает для проверки нашей подписи, но не подходит для их подписи. А почему?

Если мы сначала формируем текстовую строку, потом создаем отсоединенную подпись по ней, и потом всё это кодируем в base64, то они формируют два JSON'а: HEADER и PAYLOAD, потом кодируют их по отдельности в base64, и вот потом формируют подпись по строке HEADERbase64.PAYLOADbase64. А потом уже и подпись кодируют в base64.

Итого, метод для проверки их подписи выглядит как-то так:

```
public static bool ValidateSignature(byte[] data, byte[] signature, X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    bool result = false;
    using (var csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) certificate.PublicKey.Key)
    {
        using (var hasher = new SHA256Managed())
        {
            var hash = hasher.ComputeHash(data);
            string id = CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256");
            bool isDataok = csp.VerifyData(data, id, signature);
            bool isHashOk = csp.VerifyHash(hash, id, signature);

            //  можно ещё так
            //RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter rsaDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(csp);
            //rsaDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
            //bool isHashOk2 = rsaDeformatter.VerifySignature(hash, signature);

            result = isDataok && isHashOk;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: А не подскажите, каким образом вы отлаживали всё? Я написал код для authnrequest и просто смотрел, на сколько он похож на запрос из методички. Response, я через расширение для firefox отправлял POST`ом, но видать когда так делаешь он не видит в куки сессию-сайта. Развернул OpenAM, но во всех уроках одну OpenAM зацикливают на другую OpenAM. Пытался в OpenAM создать свой SP, но та ругается на файл метаданных

Comment: Отлаживал обычным debug'ом в Visual Studio, запросы отправляю через HttpWebRequest. Также, может знаете, есть лог авторизации на стороне ЕСИА: https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/logs/auth/

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, HEADERbase64.PAYLOADbase64 же нужно проверять прямо так как они пришли? Они в base64urlsafe. Не надо перекодировать в base64? Взял сертификат из https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/idp/shibboleth но ValidateSignature возвращает false стабильно.

Comment: У меня приходит `HEADER.PAYLOAD.SIGNATURE`. В `VerifyData` передаю: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HEADER.PAYLOAD), Convert.FromBase64String(SIGNATURE), esiaCert`

Comment: Давно дело было, но что-то мне припоминается, что с их стороны проверялось не так, как подписывалось. Если в их сторону нужно подписывать JSON, то то от них, кажется, приходит подпись на base64. И нужно помнить, что base64 в .NET не вполне соответствует стандартам и нужно поискать реализацию методов по стандартам.

Answer (score 0):

А вообще уже есть в NuGet полезнейшая библиотечка, с которой всё становится легче:

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=esia.net

В наши времена первопроходимцев так не баловали :))